# Jira Gadgets Development Structure

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

I need to develop more Gadgets in the same plugin, the gadgets will look pretty the same, what change is the resource they need to access and display. What's the best way to do this?

Do I need to create an xml file for each gadget even if it's the same?

For the Java part can I use a single class with different path for each gadget, like:
@Path("generate-gadget1"), @Path("generate-gadget2")...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a separate XML file for each gadget. You can create multiple REST endpoints within one class by using @Path.

You might get more replies if you ask these questions on the JIRA developers forum at http://forums.atlassian.com/forum.jspa?forumID=100